# Could time flow differently​ in full-immersion virtual realities?

Tags: virtual-reality, illusion

In a society where full-immersion virtual reality is common, how much more of a hurdle would it be to trick the mind into accepting a different passage of time?

For example; you enter a virtual reality and seem to spend a year in it, but in reality only a few hours have passed.

Comment: 1) You should watch the movie *Inception*. 2) That's really not how VR works, but given that we don't actually have full-immersion VR (or data for it yet), the story possibilities are endless.

Comment: That's one of the plot elements in the _Otherland_ series by Tad Williams, which involves full immersion VR.

Comment: Also seen in "boy and his tank".

Comment: Do you mean direct brain stimulation? Or VR costume? Or what? Or are you asking us to find a way for this to seem plausible?

Comment: This could be in a top 100 of the most established sci fi concepts of all times. If you enter a virtual reality, time passes at a different rate. Mr. Picard from Star Trek once lived an entire live in 20 minutes (or so). If you want to be more scientifically accurate than Star Trek and all those other countless examples, you should already have a concept of how your VR works and also how the human brain works because we don't know. Could you either explain that to the best of your ability and use a hard science tag or just accept that it's an established concept?

Comment: Easy. Step 1: load up VR video game. Step 2: Play for "a couple of hours". Step 3: take helmet off, realize "a couple of hours" was actually more like eight and it's now 3am. I did this all the time at uni, minus the VR part.

Comment: @Alfy I do not think Inception is a good example here. Dreams are a reality and we perceive time differently when dreaming - I know that from personal experience. This isn't science fiction. If you want a better example advice him to sleep

Comment: We use various ways to make things "feel" faster/slower that are used today in the car industry.  Things like windscreen shape, ride level and suspension. Combine this with our perception of the situation and time feels different. It's why you can drive at 70mph on the motorway but because there is traffic you still feel like you're going slowly

Comment: @ECiurleo Sorry many people have answered in a similar way, but I can only ping one and I chose you. Time moving feeling differently is absolutely not the same as time passing at a different rate. One example: No matter how boring your traffic jam is, you will never be able to master the trumpet any faster compared to the outside world no matter how boring your traffic jam is.

Comment: I get what you mean, but might be worth clarifying the question around that.  To my mind, this question was also open to having a party and a few drinks and it's suddenly midnight :-p  The "trick" would be to transfer that to VR and increase the scale.

Answer (score 4):

This is a hard one.

Let's imagine that our VR device can read/stimulate every output/input neuron to the brain and thereby completely simulate a different reality. The problem remains that the internal processing of the brain is based in wetware - biology, going at biological speed. For the same quality of experience, time must pass at about the same rate. Otherwise you'd be watching reality in 'fast-forward', just like fast-forwarding a DVD you were watching. Not the same quality of experience.

An even more immersive experience would be where the state of the brain (i.e. all neuron states, all connections and connection strengths) could be read and copied (this is a tricky problem). Now we can put it on an electronic substrate, we can run it at any speed; running it faster would make the outside world appear to slow down. The problem here comes when you want to leave VR, because your brain-state is significantly different to that of the left-behind biological brain. A tricky merge operation would be required, limited by how quickly the biological brain could be updated.

So to answer the question, from a theoretical standpoint it's perfectly possible to trick the brain in this way, from a practical standpoint it's very very hard.